# increase font size in setting in my application

Tags: iphone, xcode

in my application i have to make settings button in tabbar .so using this setting i want to increase or decreases size of my text view or label  so how i can do that.please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the font of just about any text control (UILabel, UITextView, UITextField) this way:

```
[myControl setFont:[UIFont fontwithName:@"fontname" size:fontSize]];
```

Answer (score 2):

first you can use NSUserDefaults for save your settings (font size)
see this link:

http://iphone.zcentric.com/2008/08/20/using_nsuserdefaults/

and then use

[myControl setFont:[UIFont fontwithName:@"fontname" size:fontSize]];

where fontsize is fetch from the NSUSerDefaults